# How do I make a bot where if u react, it will give u a role with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, discord, discord.py

so, Ive been doing this:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='><')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I am ready Winson or not Winson :D")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(744440768667844698)
    message = await channel.send(f"Welcome to HaveNoFaith {member}, happy to be friends with you")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
     await ctx.send(f"Your Ping is {round(client.latency *1000)}ms")

@client.command()
async def Help(ctx2):
    await ctx2.send("Hi, Im WelcomeBot v1.0...\n\nPrefix: ><\n\nCommands: ping\n          help")
```

#and then Im trying to do like at the message "Welcome etc" if they react with the "check reaction" in that message, they will get a role in the discord server...

Answer (score 0):

you can make a command named `addrr`(add reaction role), which will look like this -

```
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def addrr(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, message: discord.Message, emoji: discord.Emoji,
                    role: discord.Role):
        await ctx.send(f"Setting up the reaction roles in {channel.mention}.")
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)

        def check1(reaction, user):
            return user.id is not self.client.user.id and str(reaction.emoji) in [f"{emoji}"]

        while True:
            try:
                reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check1)
                if str(reaction.emoji) == f"{emoji}":
                    await user.add_roles(role)
                    await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
            except:
                await message.delete()
                break
```

It will work like this -

`><addrr <#channel mention> <message ID> <Emoji> <@Role Mention>`

Comment: refer to [this](https://i.gyazo.com/35d0690e61eccc28541a844270cf8b7d.png) image.

Answer (score -1):

So you can add a reaction to the messages that was sended and use [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client%20wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) to wait for a reaction on that message. I recommend you to add the timeout. If you dont want to have this timeout, simply just send these message, save it into a list and in the [raw_reaction_add event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=raw_reaction_add#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) check if the emoji is the one and the message is one of the messages in your list